# How can I uninstall npm v18?

Tags: npm, uninstallation, glibc

Accidently I installed npm v18, because I had some errors from package json scripts.
Now I cannot run any npm command anymore. Every npm command responds with:

```
$ npm uninstall 18
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
```

How Can I uninstall npm and go back earlier version?

Comment: This is a library issue, not an NPM issue. Some libraries are missing so it can't run.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it finally by hard installing following this link:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server

Answer (score 0):

First, check which version of npm you currently have installed by running the following command:

npm -v

If the version displayed is not the version you want, you can try running the following command to uninstall npm:

sudo npm uninstall -g npm

After npm has been uninstalled, you can install the desired version of npm by running the following command, replacing X.X.X with the version number you want to install:

sudo npm install -g npm@X.X.X

Once the desired version of npm has been installed, you can verify that it has been installed correctly by running the npm -v command again.
I hope this helps!

Comment: npm -v shows: ' npm -v
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by node)
 '

Comment: I'll try the sudo command..

Comment: Tried as you suggested:'[admin@netwerkspel ~]$ sudo npm uninstall -g npm
[sudo] password for admin:
removed 435 packages in 11.43s
'

Comment: and then: 
$ sudo npm install -g npm@16.13.0
sudo: npm: command not found
[admin@netwerkspel ~]$ npm -v
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by node)
....'